# Getting differing values based on 3 criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Looked for an answer on this for a while and not quite sure how to ask it, much less answer it. I have a setup like the one below:

| warehouse | company | charge code | date | price | other data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | comp 1 | boxes | 2022-1-1 | 3.00 | blah blah |
| 2 | comp 1 | bags | 2022-1-1 | 1.00 | blah blah |
| 3 | comp 1 | bag2 | 2022-2-5 | 1.00 | blah blah |
| 1 | comp 2 | boxes | 2022-1-1 | 3.00 | blah blah |
| 2 | comp 2 | bags | 2022-1-1 | 1.50 | blah blah |
| 3 | comp 2 | bag2 | 2022-2-5 | 2.00 | blah blah |

I am trying to make a query that will get me the prices that are different compared to the other companies in the same warehouse with the same charge code. For example, if it were to be run on the table above, it would result in

| warehouse | company | charge code | date | price | other data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | comp 1 | bags | 2022-1-1 | 1.00 | blah blah |
| 2 | comp 2 | bags | 2022-1-1 | 1.50 | blah blah |
| 3 | comp 1 | bag2 | 2022-2-5 | 1.00 | blah blah |
| 3 | comp 2 | bag2 | 2022-2-5 | 2.00 | blah blah |

Since the box prices were the same for both companies in the same warehouse, they would be removed.

My code is

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    WITH subquery AS (***LARGE IRRELEVANT SUBQUERY***) 

    SELECT distinct
        warehouse, company, charge_code, date, price, other1, other2
    FROM
        subquery

    WHERE(price) 
        IN 
           (SELECT distinct i1.price 
            FROM M_CHG_DATE_D i1 join M_CHG_DATE_D i2
            ON i1.charge_code = i2.charge_code AND
               i2.warehouse = i2.warehouse AND
               i1.company != i2.company)

    AND (warehouse, company, charge_code, date) 
        IN
           (SELECT warehouse, company, charge_code, MAX(date) 
            FROM subquery
            GROUP BY warehouse, company, charge_code)
)

WHERE company IN 
    ('comp1', 'comp2', 'comp3', ... , 'comp n')                  
AND 
    warehouse NOT IN('list of warehouses')
ORDER BY company, charge_code, warehouse
```

Currently, instances where the companies have the same price in the same warehouse for the same charge code are not being filtered out. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

update with actual data from the table:

| warehouse | company | charge code | date | price | other data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | GEN | BB | 2022-2-5 | .032 | the same |
| C1 | MUL | BB | 2022-2-5 | .032 | the same |
| C1 | RAV | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0476 | the same |
| C1 | RMF | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0476 | the same |
| C2 | BAM | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0553 | the same |
| C2 | BUM | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0553 | the same |

which should result in

| warehouse | company | charge code | date | price | other data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | GEN | BB | 2022-2-5 | .032 | the same |
| C1 | MUL | BB | 2022-2-5 | .032 | the same |
| C1 | RAV | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0476 | the same |
| C1 | RMF | BB | 2022-1-1 | .0476 | the same |

Comment: In your sample data, there are only two companies in each warehouse. What is the expected output if there are three companies in a warehouse, with two companies having the same price and a third company with a different price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to determine which combinations of warehouse and charge code has more than one price, and fetch the matching rows:

```
select warehouse, company, charge_code, chg_date, price, other1, other2
from m_chg_date_d
where (warehouse, charge_code) in
  (
    select warehouse, charge_code
    from m_chg_date_d
    group by warehouse, charge_code
    having count(distinct price) > 1
  );
```

The query assumes that `(warehouse, company, charge_code)` is unique, that is to say, that no company has the same charge code more than once in the same warehouse. This also means that there is no need to use `distinct` in the outermost query, since all rows must be unique when the result includes warehouse, company and charge code.

In the query above, I renamed the `date` column to `chg_date`, as `date` is a reserved word in Oracle.

Comment: I tried adding this and it is still giving me results where the warehouse is the same, the charge code is the same, but the price is not different.

Comment: @vito I ran the query above on the data you provided in the question, and got the results specified. Could you please ensure the question includes your exact test data and expected results?

Comment: The query looks fine to me. (It doesn't contain that lastest price thing the original query has, but this isn't mentioned in the problem description anyway.)

Comment: @markusk I thought it worked at first, but it is now returning no values when I can manually identify some prices that are different in the same warehouse

Comment: @vito If you update the table in your question with the input and expected output, I can try to improve the query. As far as I can tell, the current query produces the expected results for the test data you provide.

Comment: @markusk I updated my question with some actual data where I noticed the problem. One thing that stands out is the date for the ones that should be showing up (but aren't) are slightly older than the others, but seeing that your solution didn't have date anywhere in it, I don't see why that would change the answer.

Comment: @vito Could you please also show the expected output for the new input?

Comment: @markusk it should return every company with that charge code in that warehouse with the prices, so that one could see the price differences. I added a couple of additional items to make the expected result clearer

Comment: @vito I ran the query on the new data, and got the expected result (four rows, all from `C1`). As far as I can tell, the query is working as specified.

Comment: @markusk I'm not sure why it isn't working on my end, it certainly removes some of the ones it's supposed to, as the results drop by about 1k rows and they seem to be correct removals, but many are still staying when they are the same price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246868/discussion-between-vito-and-markusk).

Answer (score 0):

Or, create an in-line grouping table to join the original table back with ; I don't know if the date column (I called it `dt` to avoid conflicts with reserved words) must or must not be part of the grouping criteria - works both ways ...

```
WITH
  2 -- your input , don't use in final query
  3 indata(warehouse,company,charge_code,dt,price,other_data) AS (
  4           SELECT 1,'comp 1','boxes',DATE '2022-1-1',3.00,'blah blah'
  5 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'comp 1','bags' ,DATE '2022-1-1',1.00,'blah blah'
  6 UNION ALL SELECT 3,'comp 1','bag2' ,DATE '2022-2-5',1.00,'blah blah'
  7 UNION ALL SELECT 1,'comp 2','boxes',DATE '2022-1-1',3.00,'blah blah'
  8 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'comp 2','bags' ,DATE '2022-1-1',1.50,'blah blah'
  9 UNION ALL SELECT 3,'comp 2','bag2' ,DATE '2022-2-5',2.00,'blah blah'
 10 )
 11 -- real query starts here - replace following comma with "WITH"                                                                                                                                       
 12 ,
 13 select_criteria AS (
 14   SELECT
 15     warehouse
 16   , charge_code
 17   , dt
 18   , COUNT(*) AS itemcount 
 19   , COUNT(DISTINCT price) AS pricecount
 20   FROM indata
 21   GROUP BY
 22     warehouse
 23   , charge_code
 24   , dt
 25   HAVING pricecount = itemcount
 26 )
 27 SELECT
 28   indata.*
 29 FROM indata
 30 JOIN select_criteria USING (
 31     warehouse
 32   , charge_code
 33   , dt
 34 )
 35 ORDER BY 1,2
 36 ;
 37 -- out  warehouse | company | charge_code |     dt     | price | other_data 
 38 -- out -----------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------
 39 -- out          2 | comp 1  | bags        | 2022-01-01 |  1.00 | blah blah
 40 -- out          2 | comp 2  | bags        | 2022-01-01 |  1.50 | blah blah
 41 -- out          3 | comp 1  | bag2        | 2022-02-05 |  1.00 | blah blah
 42 -- out          3 | comp 2  | bag2        | 2022-02-05 |  2.00 | blah blah
 43 -- out (4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` to check whether there is a matching row with another price.

```
SELECT *
FROM m_chg_date_d
WHERE EXISTS
( 
  SELECT NULL
  FROM m_chg_date_d other
  WHERE other.warehouse = m_chg_date_d.warehouse
  AND other.charge_code = m_chg_date_d.charge_code
  AND other.price <> m_chg_date_d.price
)
ORDER BY warehouse, charge_code, company;
```

Comment: The "irrelevant subquery" part already ensures that it is all the most recent prices, so that part is taken care of. I now just need to find different prices for the same item in each warehouse.

Comment: Then the `AND (warehouse, company, charge_code, date) IN (...)` is superfluous in your query. I have removed that part now from my query, too.